# Postgresql Regex pattern matching before a word or end of line

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have the following rows (sample) in my postgresql from which I am trying to extracts words.

```
subset:|actuals_source:|comments:February_2021_FFRPrice_RegModelsOnly_Demand Sales Volume*CSOPprice_Commit_a57f193aede
subset:|actuals_source:|comments:china_market_CSOP_Demand Sales Volume_PFJan2021
subset:|actuals_source:zeros|comments:Functional_test_2_Cores_FWD_facing_regressor_leak_fix_commit_c596a521e07
```

The words I am trying to extract starts from `comments:` and are before `Commit_c596a521e07` if the `Commit` word exists or it's till the end of line. (Also note that `Commit` can also be of lowercase as in `commit`)

So the extracted column should look like:

```
February_2021_FFRPrice_RegModelsOnly_Demand Sales Volume*CSOPprice
china_market_CSOP_Demand Sales Volume_PFJan2021
Functional_test_2_Cores_FWD_facing_regressor_leak_fix
```

I have tried the following pattern, but unfortunately it returns everything after `Commit`

`substring(col_name from '.*comments:(.*?)(?:Commit|$)')`

Is there a way to limit the selection, such that it returns words only before `Commit` (wherever Commit exists) or till the end of line.

Comment: Your data is in capture group 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match `c` in `Commit` in a case insensitive way using `[cC]` and make sure you match a `_` before `Commit` and use

```sql
substring(col_name from 'comments:(.*?)(_[Cc]ommit|$)')
```

Note that the [`substring` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-matching.html) returns the Group 1  value here:

> If the pattern contains any parentheses, the portion of the text that matched the first parenthesized subexpression (the one whose left parenthesis comes first) is returned

The pattern matches

- `comments:` - a literal string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(_[Cc]ommit|$)` - Group 2 (this value won't be returned): `_Commit` or `_commit` or end of string.

See a [PostgreSQL demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aYDK6bYE1a4NNymHX8TfQh/0):

```sql
WITH demo(col_name) AS (
   VALUES
      ('subset:|actuals_source:|comments:February_2021_FFRPrice_RegModelsOnly_Demand Sales Volume*CSOPprice_Commit_a57f193aede'),
      ('subset:|actuals_source:|comments:china_market_CSOP_Demand Sales Volume_PFJan2021'),
      ('subset:|actuals_source:zeros|comments:Functional_test_2_Cores_FWD_facing_regressor_leak_fix_commit_c596a521e07')
   )
SELECT substring(col_name from 'comments:(.*?)(_[Cc]ommit|$)') FROM demo;
```

Output:

[image]